# why my code does work on chrome and not once compile using cordova

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova, kendo-ui

i'm working on a project using cordova / eclipse / kendo ui and i'm going through a weird behave ...

i developed a sample of test to show you ..

when i try to run that sample on google chrome, it does work, but once compiled and running on my phone (which is a nexus 4 by the way even if it doesnt really matter i think ..) it doesnt work...

in this example, we have something simple, a menu with three items and a view which differs depends on what button you click on.

on google chrome, it works, i mean when i click on the first button, it shows "first", same for second and so on ..

when i compile the project with eclipse and run it on my phone, the message is the same whatever the button i clicked on ..

here is my sample of code :

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Librairies -->
<script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fonction d'init -->
<script src="init/cordovaInit.js"></script>
<!-- Controleurs -->
<script src="controlers/panelControler.js"></script>
<!-- EndScript -->
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
<div data-role="view" id="drawer-home" data-layout="drawer-layout" data-title="search">
<div id="search">
     <div id="first">
      <p>first</p>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
      <p>second</p>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
      <p>third</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="drawer" id="my-drawer" style="width: 270px" data-views="['/', 'drawer-home']">
<ul data-role="listview" data-type="group">
<li>Menu
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#drawer-home" onClick="panelControler('first')">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#drawer-home" onClick="panelControler('second')">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#drawer-home" onClick="panelControler('third')">Third</a></li>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div data-role="layout" data-id="drawer-layout" data-layout="overview-layout">
<header data-role="header">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#my-drawer" data-icon="drawer-button" data-align="left"></a>
    <span>Test</span>
  </div>
 </header>
</div>
<script>
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
panelControler('first');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the very simple javascript i'm using to test :

```
function panelControler(action){
alert("panelControler");
if (action === 'first'){
    alert("first show");
    $("#first").show();
    $("#second").hide();
    $("#third").hide();
}
else if (action === 'second'){
    alert("second show");
    $("#second").show();
    $("#first").hide();
    $("#third").hide();
}
else if (action === 'third'){
    alert("third show");
    $("#third").show();
    $("#second").hide();
    $("#first").hide();
}
}
```

Comment: What is `<script src="init/cordovaInit.js"></script>`? How are you "compiling" - with cordova CLI?

Comment: no, i'm using eclipse

Comment: Where did you get cordova at? How did you set it up with Eclipse? Did you run the cordova create command and then point Eclipse to the generated android project?

Comment: i did this exactly yesterday : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the second Q/A pair from the [Kendo UI Mobile FAQ](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/kendo-mobile-faq#q).